# High Memory Usage on Heroku RubyOnRail App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, spree

I'm using Heroku to deploy my RubyOnRail app, and use Spree CMS
Like in pic, I got very high Memory Usage, but very low requests/min. Dont know what happen here. Someone can give me a suggest please ?

[image]

Comment: It is 0 worker, and 1 dyno Hobby.

Comment: What server do you use (e.g. unicorn, puma, webrick)? How is that server configured?

Comment: I dont know, I just created app on Heroku. But I got this on Web Console
web bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

worker bundle exec rake qc:work

Is that mean unicorn ?

Comment: Yes, that mean you are running a `unicorn` server. Can you please add the content of your  `config/unicorn.rb` file to your question?

Comment: worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end
after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

Comment: God, it not break line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/heroku.html):

> We have found that the 1X and 2X dynos do not perform at a production-ready efficiency for a Spree store. Although some stores will work fine on the 2X dynos, if you’re having speed problems we recommend running on the PX (“performance”) dynos only.

That said: A Heroku Hobby dyno has only 512MB what is below the hardware requirements of this application. They recommend running PX dynos that have at least 2.5GB RAM.